# adding each element each row of two columns together in the same file without loops in R

Tags: r

Say you have a file with two columns and 3 rows:

```
A  B
1  2
2  3
3  4
```

I would like to, with out a loop, add each element of A to the same row in B together: 1 + 2, 2 + 3, 3 + 4.

How do I do this in R?

This to the best of my knowledge is not a Homework Problem.

Comment: where are your two rows? you may mean two columns..

Comment: `with(yourdataframe, A + B)`

Comment: Lets assume your data frame is called `df` you can also write `df$A + df$B` or `df[,1] + df[,2]`.

Comment: with `rowSums(df)` you do not need to specify any other parameter.

Comment: Yes, Paulo ... you are correct. I need another red Bull :-)

Comment: Paulo, is there also a way to do row differences?

Comment: @ChrisRigano there isn't a `rowDiff` if that's what you mean. But otherwise you simply replace the `+` in the other suggestions with `-`

Comment: thanks! Making the transition from python to r Chris

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A summary of options suggested in the comments (and some others):

```
dd<-data.frame(
    A= 1:3,
    B= 2:4
)
```

You can get the sum of the columns with

- `dd$A + dd$B`
- `rowSums(dd)`
- `with(dd, A + B)`
- `dd[,1]+ dd[,2]`
- `dd[,"A"]+ dd[,"B"]`
- `apply(dd, 1, sum)`
- `do.call('+', dd)`
- `Reduce("+",dd)`